# Properties of object null even after setting

Tags: java

I have been looking at this for a while. First off, here is some code:

`MyActivity.java`:

```
MeasurementType type = handler.getMeasurementType(DEFAULT_TYPE);
ArrayList<Unit> unitsConverted = new ArrayList<Unit>();
unitsConverted.addAll(Arrays.asList(type.getUnits()));
```

`DataBaseHandler.java`:

```
public MeasurementType getMeasurementType(String measurementType) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int num = getMeasurementUnitCount(measurementType);
        MeasurementType mType = MeasurementType.getMeasurementType(measurementType);
        Unit[] units = new Unit[num];
        String getUnits = "SELECT unit_name, view FROM " + measurementType;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(getUnits, null);
        for(int i = 0; i <= units.length-1; i++) {
            if(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Unit u = new Unit();
                u.setUnitName(cursor.getString(0));
                u.setView(cursor.getInt(1));
                units[i] = u;
            }
        }

        mType.setUnits(units);
        return mType;
    }
```

I am not quite sure why this is happening but after this line:
`mType.setUnits(units)`
The debugger is telling me that the property is null...
`num` is 21 which is right, the array `units` goes from 0 to 20, which is right.
Here is my implementation of the `setUnits(units)` method in my `MeasurementType` class:

```
protected void setUnits(Unit[] passedUnits) {
       units = new Unit[passedUnits.length+1];
       System.arraycopy(passedUnits, 0, units, 0, passedUnits.length);
    }
```

it works ok too...
in fact when the method getMeasurement is finished and I am back in my activity, it still says null.

However stepping through to creating the `ArrayList` and then doing:
`unitsConverted.addAll(Arrays.asList(type.getUnits()));`

works fine...the `ArrayList` is populated fine. But one thing that I don't understand is why the debugger is telling me that the property is null...it has been happening to this specific circumstance for some time now, I haven't been able to fix it.

Further information you might need to know is that `MeasurementType` is an abstract class that instantiates a subclass based on a string that is passed to it, so it definitely creates a subclass and intialises everything :)

Comment: What do you mean "the property is null"? Which property, and how are you asking?

Comment: @chrylis so in the debugger I see the mType variable, I then expand that variable in Intellij's variables window, I then see the class variable units which should be set to the array that has been passed to the setUnits method in my code above, but it says units = null

Comment: Print this value out with `System.out.println`. Otherwise you might be debugging the debugger (though it's unlikely).

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes I have tried that, it is fully initialised, it gives 21 for the length and I got it to print out all of the values too...

Comment: @user2405469 You mean the value returned by `mType.getUnits` is OK? If so, why do you care what the debugger shows?

Comment: @peter.petrov Because I would like to see it there.

Comment: Well, you can check the bugs of your IDE then and/or report a new one. Also, you can try clearing the caches of your IDE and reload your project, then try again. Also, you can try in another IDE. This seems to be an IDE issue.